# How to add a GridView to a Visual Web Part?

Tags: development, visual-studio, visual-web-part, user-controls, gridview

I'm new to SharePoint and am developing a simple World Clock Visual Web Part, following this [blogpost from SharePoint Hero](https://sharepointhero.wordpress.com/2014/07/20/adding-world-clock-and-exchange-rates-web-parts-to-sharepoint/).

In the blogpost the instructor describes adding a GridView to the Web Part, but doesn't elaborate on how to do so.

I've taken a guess and added a GridView to the UserControl file, but can't figure out how to reference it in order for it to be populated.

My VisualWebPart.cs file:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    SPTimeZoneCollection timeZoneColl = SPRegionalSettings.GlobalTimeZones;

    // Creating the table
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();


    // **** The two lines that aren't working correctly ****
    VisualWebPart1UserControl control = (VisualWebPart1UserControl)Page.LoadControl(_ascxPath);
    GridView grdWorldClock = control.FindControl("GridView1") as GridView;


    // Adding columns
    dt.Columns.Add("Description");
    dt.Columns.Add("Time Zone");

    foreach (SPTimeZone tz in timeZoneColl) {

        DateTime currentLocalDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime currentDestDateTime = tz.UTCToLocalTime(currentLocalDateTime.ToUniversalTime());

        // Adding Rows
        DataRow dr;
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Description"] = tz.Description.ToString();
        dr["Time Zone"] = currentDestDateTime.ToString();
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    // Connecting Data Source to our GridView
    grdWorldClock.DataSource = dt;
    grdWorldClock.DataBind();

    dt.Dispose();
}
```

And the GridView I've added to my VisualWebPartUserControl.ascx file:

`<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>`

Additionally, I attempted to populate the `DataTable` object manually, in case for whatever reason `timeZoneColl` was empty, but this didn't work either:

```
DataTable dr = dt.newRow();
dr["Description"] = "The time for this zone"
dr["Time Zone"] = "EST"
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```

The result:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? Am I grabbing the GridView from the UserControl incorrectly, or perhaps adding the DataSource to it wrong?

Answer (score 2):

**You have two options**

**Option 1:** Change the `grid view ID` to `grdWorldClock` at

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
```

To be

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdWorldClock" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
```

**Option 2:** Just change the below code to use the default grid view ID `GridView1`

```
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

---

> **Note:** you can **also** add the gridview control from the toolbox
>
> [image]

Comment: Changing the ID of the GridView tag in the UserControl doesn't seem to have any effect. I've changed it to `grdWorldClock` and the GridView still doesn't populate. 

Changing the variable name in the .cs file from `grdWorldClock` to `GridView1`, as you demonstrate in Option 2, gives me a new error specific to that line: `The name GridView1 does not exist in the current context`.

Comment: Have you tried to remove your grid view tag and add a new grid view from the toolbox as above mentioned then in the code, replace the grdWorldClock with your new gridview ID?

Comment: Yes, I've deleted the old tag and created a new one directly from the toolbox and the error persists.

Comment: Did you replaced the grdWorldClock with your new gridview ID?

Comment: Apologies, yes I have. The variable is named `GridView1`, which is the same as the GridView tag ID `GridView1`